# what web service and format to use

Tags: android, json, rest, service

i'd like to aks, if someone were to create a web site, let's say for example: a site for storing information on an online database, what would be the recommended web service (SOAP or REST) and format to use (XML or JSON) if there will be server - client transactions/interactions and a client application will also be used in an android platform?

also, i'm curious. does anyone know if google uses REST web service and JSON format for the GMAIL in android?

thanks

ads

Comment: It'd be great if you can mark answers as correct or provide comment as to why you still haven't accepted any answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what they use in the GMAIL application. 
But I'd prefer REST and JSON because of two simple reasons

- REST is easier to access, since forming the request is not gonna take much time.
- JSON lib is bundled with android and is smaller in size when compared with its XML counterpart.

Comment: i do agree go for REST + JSON